# What is the best way to express an argument in sentence logic?

Tags: logic

I have to translate follo wing sentence into SL (sentence letters). I have also Indicate which English sentences I am representing with which.

> Bill will win the race if and only if Gladys either breaks a leg or has a hangover.

I wrote

- $B:$ Bill win will the race
  and
- $G$: Gladys either breaks a leg or an arm or has an hangover

Which leads me to : $B\equiv G$

Yet, I thought also to another answer: 
$A$

- :Bill will win the race.
- $B$:Gladys breaks a leg or an arm.
- $C$:Gladys has a hangover.
  $A≡(B∨C)$

Which one should be considered as the best? the shortest one or the one expressiong the

Comment: Just a small note: you should use $\iff$ for iff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea that the author had with this problem was definitely to use the one with

$$A\iff (B\lor C).$$

With this expression, you break the sentence into as many atomic parts as you can.